# Deleting CommandBarButtons from the Application.CommandBars["Cell"] isn't removing them from all open workbooks on ThisAddIn_Shutdown event

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I have a C# VSTO application with .NET 4.0 that uses two custom CommandBarButtons in the Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.CommandBars["Cell"] context menu. I create the buttons once on the ThisAddIn_Startup event and they work wonderfully for all workbooks. If my add in is shut down at some point without shutting down Excel then an issue occurs if there's more than 1 open workbook. Only the active workbook's right click context menu has the buttons deleted.

The code:

```
public partial class ThisAddIn
{
    private const string TAG_PASTE_EVENT = "PASTE EVENT";
    private const string TAG_COPY_EVENT = "COPY EVENT";
    private Office.CommandBarButton copy_event, paste_event;

    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            DefineShortcutMenu();

            /*
             * Other start up stuff that works fine
             */
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ExceptionHandler.HandleException(ex);
        }
    }

    private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        /*
         * Other shut down stuff that works fine 
         */

        // Remove the right click menu buttons
        foreach (Office.CommandBarControl control in Application.CommandBars["Cell"].Controls)
        {
            if (control.Tag.Equals(TAG_PASTE_EVENT))
            {
                control.Delete(true);
            }
            else if (control.Tag.Equals(TAG_COPY_EVENT))
            {
                control.Delete(true);
            }
        }
    }

    private void copy_event_Click(Office.CommandBarButton Ctrl, ref bool CancelDefault)
    {
        // Copy code
    }

    private void paste_event_Click(Office.CommandBarButton Ctrl, ref bool CancelDefault)
    {
        // Paste code
    }

    private void DefineShortcutMenu()
    {
        // Create and add the paste button
        paste_event = (Office.CommandBarButton)Application.CommandBars["Cell"].Controls.Add(Office.MsoControlType.msoControlButton, missing, missing, 1, true);
        paste_event.Style = Office.MsoButtonStyle.msoButtonCaption;
        paste_event.Caption = "Paste Event";
        paste_event.Tag = TAG_PASTE_EVENT;
        paste_event.DescriptionText = "Stuff happens";
        paste_event.Enabled = false;
        paste_event.Click += paste_event_Click;

        // Create and add the copy button
        copy_event = (Office.CommandBarButton)Application.CommandBars["Cell"].Controls.Add(Office.MsoControlType.msoControlButton, missing, missing, 1, true);
        copy_event.Style = Office.MsoButtonStyle.msoButtonCaption;
        copy_event.Caption = "Copy Event";
        copy_event.Tag = TAG_COPY_EVENT;
        copy_event.DescriptionText = "Stuff happens";
        copy_event.Enabled = false;
        copy_event.Click += copy_event_Click;
    }

    #region VSTO generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InternalStartup()
    {
        this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
        this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

I'm using Excel 2013 which I know has one bug related to the right click context menu (which is why I'm using a foreach for the CommandBarControls instead of using the global variables). Any workflows that you've found that work would be much appreciated!

TO CLARIFY: Everything works fine, the only issue is CommandBarButtons not deleting from the right click context menus of the non-active workbooks if the Add In is shut down. If the Add In is turned back on during the same session all the workbooks are given the Copy and Paste buttons again meaning the workbooks whose context menus didn't update properly now have 2 Copy buttons and 2 Paste buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command Bars were deprecated with Office 2010. You need to use the Fluent UI controls instead.

See [Customizing Context Menus in Office 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee691832(v=office.14).aspx) for more information.